# Clear all values in nested ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hashmap

How can I remove all values from ruby has. I don't want to remove keys just values.

For example:

here is my hash:    `{'a'=>{'b'=>'c'},'d'=>'e','f'=>{'g'=>''}}`

I want this:   `{'a'=>{'b'=>nil},'d'=>nil,'f'=>{'g'=>nil}}`

I don't want to delete the nested hashes. The nesting level varies from one to six levels

thanx

Comment: Recursion is the only option I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = {'a'=>{'b'=>'c'},'d'=>'e','f'=>{'g'=>''}}

def clean_hash h
 h.each do  |key, value| 
   if value.instance_of? Hash
     clean_hash value
   else
     h[key] = nil
   end
 end
end

clean_hash h
#{"a"=>{"b"=>nil}, "d"=>nil, "f"=>{"g"=>nil}}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write custom `delete_values!` method, like this:

```
class Hash
  def delete_values!
    each_key do |key|
      self[key].is_a?(Hash) ? self[key].delete_values! : self[key] = nil
    end
  end
end

{'a'=>{'b'=>'c'},'d'=>'e','f'=>{'g'=>''}}.delete_values!
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>nil}, "d"=>nil, "f"=>{"g"=>nil}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
h = {'a'=>{'b'=>'c'},'d'=>'e','f'=>{'g'=>''}}

def cleaned_hash(h)
  h.reduce({}) do |memo, (key, val)|
    memo[key] = if val.is_a? Hash
                  cleaned_hash(val)
                else
                  nil
                end
    memo
  end
end

cleaned_hash h
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>nil}, "d"=>nil, "f"=>{"g"=>nil}}
```

This will not modify your hash but instead give you cleaned copy

Comment: `case` for one expression is bad practice.